# Java Graphics Not Executing Paint Function Without extends

Tags: java, swing, graphics, paint

I've been battling a bit (or a lot) with Java's Graphics, I've been going through the documentation and tutorials for drawing Java Graphics.

Every example I've found seems to have a main class that extends a JPanel and then calls itself which executes the paint function somehow.

Is it possible to draw graphics without using extends at all? I have a basic program

```
import javax.swing.*;
import awt.Graphics;

public class basicWindow {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("Basic Window");
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JInternalFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        frame.add(panel);

        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {

        g.fillRect(5, 15, 50, 75);

    }

}
```

This opens a window but doesn't draw anything which I was I expect because I don't know how to execute the paint function.

If I try

```
Graphics graphic = new Graphics();

paint(graphic);
```

It doesn't work because it's complaining about the class being abstract.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to draw graphics without using extends at all?

Yes, it sure is possible. As mentioned by @HovercraftFullOfEels in a comment:

> You can draw on a `BufferedImage`..

If you display that image in a `JLabel` (lets call it `label`) then to get the screen to update after the image has changed, simply call:

```
label.repaint();
```

Answer (score 2):

You will want to read the tutorials and follow them. Java Swing uses passive graphics, and your code needs to respect this.

- As per the tutorials, have your drawing class extend JPanel.
- Draw within the paintComponent method override
- Don't forget the `@Override` annotation.

Regarding,

> Is it possible to draw graphics without using extends at all?

- You can draw on a BufferedImage and display **that** within the paintComponent method. This still requires that you extend the component.
- You can draw with a Graphics object obtained by calling `getGraphics()` on a component, however if you do this, the image will not be stable, and you risk throwing a NPE, and so this is **not** recommended.

Comment: The extend part is part of the problem, I was hoping to use it without extends

Comment: @Trent: the best answer is don't. Why are you not desiring to use standard Swing protocol?

Comment: I've run into several problems with extends before where my class is then forced to remain as that object unconditionally

Comment: @Trent: usually those types of issues are best solved through good MVC separation of concerns. And by doing that, you leave the graphics and view as it should be.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: post an answer please